# alias in select stament mysql with @ and :=?

Tags: mysql

I just saw the following mysql syntax and havent found out what it is so far. Not sure what to google for:

```
SELECT @M_ID:=member.M_ID FROM member LEFT OUTER JOIN member_status
ON member.M_ID=member_status.M_ID
WHERE member_status.M_ID IS NULL;
```

What's this `@M_ID:=` doing exactly and what it is called?

Comment: That's a user-defined variable. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: Have a look at [`User-Defined Variables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Don't google for anything. Read the official documentation (see the link in the comments above).

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you, had never heard of that in MysQL!

Comment: whoever wrote that, assigned M_ID as a user variable, but then never used it again. Most probably he tried to use the variable for something, then changed his mind, forgot to remove the variable assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@M_ID` is a variable.

`@M_ID :=` is the syntax for assigning a variable in a `select` statement.  (For `set`, `@M_ID =` is sufficient.)

This query:

```
SELECT @M_ID := member.M_ID
FROM member LEFT OUTER JOIN
     member_status
     ON member.M_ID = member_status.M_ID
WHERE member_status.M_ID IS NULL;
```

is returning the rows from `member` that have no corresponding rows in `member_status`.  `@M_ID` is assigning one of these values to a variable.

This looks like a bad coding practice, because multiple ids might be mismatched, and the expression only returns one.  If you wanted to get all of them into a comma-delimited list, for instance, you could do:

```
SELECT @M_ID := GROUP_CONCAT(member.M_ID)
FROM member LEFT OUTER JOIN
     member_status
     ON member.M_ID = member_status.M_ID
WHERE member_status.M_ID IS NULL;
```

I'm not advocating storing the values as a list; just pointing out that the code might return only one of many values.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, a user-defined variable.